# Purpose of using multiple AWS Elastic network interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-network-interface

I am reading about `AWS Elastic network interfaces`. Can someone tell me a good practical example of creating multiple Network Interfaces ?

Based on what I understood:

Assume there's an application that is in EC2. This application has several user functions and admin functions. We create 2 subnets, 1 for users and another for admins. We can create another `Elastic network interfaces` for admin users to access EC2. Is my understanding correct ? what are some common use cases for ENIs?

Comment: Is your question "what are some common use cases for ENIs?"

Comment: @jarmod Yes. I have edited the post as well.

Comment: You can implement simple failover with an ENI. When a primary instance fails, you start up a standby instance, then move the ENI from the primary to the standby, hence promoting the standby to primary. Because the ENI has the same IP address, regardless of which instance it's attached to, clients do not have to make any DNS modifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the use case you describe is one of the common reasons to have multiple ENIs on a single instance.

There was a similar question on ServerFault with some good answers. It’s not specific to AWS, but the reasoning can be applied here as well: https://serverfault.com/questions/129935/is-there-any-reason-to-have-2-nics-on-a-server

Comment: Ok. The answers suggest to separate network functions. But is it for ease or are there any other benefit of doing so ?

Comment: It is the _only_ way of placing the same instance in multiple subnets. There can be all kinds of reasons and applications for _why_ you would want to do that.

Comment: Some of which are different endpoints for different functions, security, using the instance as a router, etc.

Answer (score 3):

A very common use case for using **multiple ENIs** is in ECS and `awsvpc` network mode.

The `awsvpc` network mode [requires extra ENIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) on your instances to use. This:

> simplifies container networking and gives you more control over how containerized applications communicate with each other and other services within your VPCs.

`awsvpc` network mode is also required when using Fargate launch type, but that is managed by AWS. If you want to use the `awsvpc` mode on your **container instances** (EC2 Launch type) you will have to ensure that your instance can accommodate the extra ENI (one per task) with proper security groups.

There are also **AWS managed ENIs** that are created in your VPC. Examples are VPC Interface endpoints and lambda VPC integration.